# PHP - Page times out when trying to access an object

Tags: php

So i've been developing an Admin panel and I just stumbled on a problem I haven't seen before.

When I'm trying to access my 'PageContent' object the page seems to instantly time out. The object is filled correctly. The object array im trying to access only has 12 records.

Function that creates the objects:

```
public function getPages()
{
    $pages = array();
    $rs = $this->con->fetchResult($this->con->doQuery("SELECT * FROM PANEL_PAGES"));
    foreach($rs as $row)
    {
        $pages[] = new ContentPage($row[0]->iPid, $row[0]->strTitle, $row[0]->dlastEdit, $row->strBy);
    }

    return $pages;        
}
```

Index.php

```
ob_start();
session_start(); // Start a session

<?php 

if(!Engine::adminIsLogged())  {  
    header("Location: " . ADMIN_BASE);   
} 
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Content.page.php

```
<? 
require ADMIN_TPL . "head.tpl";

require ADMIN_BIN . "controllers/page.php";
$pageMan = new PageManager();
$pages = $pageMan->getPages();

?>
```

I try to access the objects in this way. Been doing it like this for years, so I'm stuck really.

```
<?php
    foreach($pages as $page)
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $page->getPid();  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page->getTitle(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page->getLastEdited(); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $page->getEditedBy(); ?></td>
        <td>
            <a href="index.php?page=editpage?id=<?php echo $page->getPid() ?>" title="Edit"><img src="resources/images/icons/pencil.png" alt="Edit" /></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with `times out` ? And did you check the error logs?

Comment: post error log output.

Comment: Just checked the log. But there is nothing regarding this issue.
It just gives the regular "Webpage cannot be displayed"